# Transition matrix based on amounts

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dataset:

```
example_data <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4,4,6,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2,3,4),
                       ContractID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,7,10,11,12,13),
                       Day = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                       Rating = c("A","B","A","A","A","C","A","A","C","A","D","C","A","B","C","D"),
                       Amount = c(79,71,74,10,20,30,18,91,33,59,90,32,5,71,79,60))
```

and what I would like to create is a transition matrix from day 1 to day 2 and day 2 to day 3.

It would look like something like this:

[image: Transition matrix]

Of course, the labels Day 1 and Day 2 are for illustrative purposes only.

For example: cell A, C with the value -41, we get it by 33 - 74, since the amount decreased from day 1 to day 2.

Observe that there are some small caveats:

- We consider only contractIDs and IDs that are present in Day 1 and Day 2.
- The contractID and ID are unique together and not only the ID.

I was wondering how one would be able to create such a table, without actually splitting it into two datasets, for the two days.

Comment: Where is `Day 3`?

Comment: See the column Days in data. I should rename it to Day. My apologies.

Comment: No no, I mean on your table...You are showing the differences in day 1 and day 2 only

Comment: My apologies for my misunderstanding. The transition of Day 2 to Day 3 would be a new table of the same kind. Unless there is another representation format of this in a table, but I do not think that is possible.